# Unable to use spark kryo serialization

Tags: apache-spark-2.0

I am unable to user the kryo serializer in spark-2.0.2.  In my scala driver code, I have.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
parkConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","64m")
parkConf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer","64k")
```

However, this generates the following error:

> [Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 4]17/03/30 10:15:34 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 157. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value.

In addition, I tried setting the same properties in spark-defaults.conf, with the same error.  Give the error is reporting that the "Available" size is 0:, it would seem that my settings are being ignored.

Answer (score 3):

I now understand.  "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max" must be big enough to accept all the data in the partition, not just a record.  For a partition containing 512mb of 256 byte arrays, the buffer.max must be on the order of 768mb.  I didn't see this explained anywhere in the docs, and was under the impression that buffer.max had to be big enough to accept the largest serialized record in the partition.